Using TEXTJOIN and nested IFERROR/IF functions
I am trying to use TEXTJOIN together with IFERROR and IF to look up values from other tabs and combine (where relevant). The first tab might not have value to receive and in which case want to get from other tab, hence using IFERROR. However I seem to be getting the result plus a whole lot of FALSE responses.
My formula:=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IFERROR(IF(C22='Paste firm-level scorecard'!$A$4:$A$29,'Paste firm-level scorecard'!$H$4:$H$29),IF('ESG Scorecard 2024'!A22='Paste fund-specific RFI'!$A$4:$A$92,'Paste fund-specific RFI'!$J$4:$J$92)))
I used this which seemed to work but the TEXTJOIN although not really needed in this case but wanted to drag down whole sheet and in another row combining text is needed and VLOOKUP seems to stop at 1st result - =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C23,'Paste firm-level scorecard'!$A$1:$K$29,8,0),VLOOKUP($A23,'Paste fund-specific RFI'!$A$1:$L$92,10,0)))
This also worked where combining the text lookup - =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF($A27='Paste fund-specific RFI'!A:A,'Paste fund-specific RFI'!J:J,""))
Basically wanting to create single formula to drag down whole sheet to and pick up where want to combine look ups.
Any suggestions?
As above my formula:=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IFERROR(IF(C22='Paste firm-level scorecard'!$A$4:$A$29,'Paste firm-level scorecard'!$H$4:$H$29),IF('ESG Scorecard 2024'!A22='Paste fund-specific RFI'!$A$4:$A$92,'Paste fund-specific RFI'!$J$4:$J$92)))
Was hoping to get the relevant value from the relevant tab without FALSE responses.

Please add the tag for the used spreadsheet application.... (We do not like guesing...)

Sorry what do you mean spreadsheet application - its excel on office365 and I think the latest but not 100% sure.

I exactly mean office365  or google-sheets or some other app. Now I added [tag:office265] as a tag to the question, so the office365 experts can find this question easier....

Oh ok thank you. Understood.
